# NGINX - Handle both ID or Username

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-config

I have 2 urls like this:

**1 - example.com/user/JohnFifty/**

**2 - example.com/user/45771/**

Both work, but only one or the other. I want to allow both, which is enabled in the PHP code.

I have tried

```
if ($arg_id ~ ([\d]+)[^\d]) {
   rewrite ^/user/([^/]*)/$ /user.php?id=$1 last;
}
rewrite ^/user/([^/]*)/$ /user.php?username=$1 last;
```

In order to detect the case, how can I make NGINX detect if the GET request is of a ID or string (username)?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the case where a [`map`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) block can be very helpful, being used among with the [named capture groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html):

```
map $id $id_type {
    ~^\d+$   id;
    default  username;
}

server {
    ...
    rewrite ^/user/(?<id>[^/]+)/$ /user.php?$id_type=$id;
    ...
}
```